# Android emulator on apple silicon (arm64) could be run only using sudo mode

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm trying to start android emulator on apple silicon mac and I'm always getting the same results:

1. Running emulator directly through Android Studio (the latest stable version, Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4) causes a problem, when the process qemu-system-arch64 stucks and uses 99% CPU (there is no emulator's screen or something like than). Such behavior produces some logs:

internal-error-msg.txt says:

```
emuglConfig_init: blacklisted=0 has_guest_renderer=0, mode: auto, option: (null)

emuglConfig_init: auto-selected swiftshader_indirect based on conditions and UI preference 3

emuglConfig_init: GPU emulation enabled using 'swiftshader_indirect' mode

Deciding if GLDirectMem/Vulkan should be enabled. Selected renderer: 8 API level: 32 host GPU blacklisted? 0

Swiftshader selected, enabling Vulkan.

Enabling GLDirectMem
Enabling Vulkan
Adding to the library search path: /Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader
```

opengl_log.txt says:

```
Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu info

RenderWindow: CMD_INITIALIZE w=1080 h=2280
FrameBuffer::initialize
SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib]

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib]: not found in map, open for the first time

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib] (posix): begin

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib] (posix,darwin): call dlopen

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib] (posix,darwin): failed, try again with [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib]

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib] failed (posix). dlerror: []

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib]

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib]: not found in map, open for the first time

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib] (posix): begin

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib] (posix,darwin): call dlopen

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib] (posix,darwin): failed, try again with [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib]

SharedLibrary::open for [/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib] failed (posix). dlerror: []

SharedLibrary::open for [libGLESv2.dylib]: not found in map, open for the first time

SharedLibrary::open for [libGLESv2.dylib] (posix): begin

SharedLibrary::open for [libGLESv2.dylib] (posix,darwin): call dlopen

SharedLibrary::open for [libGLESv2.dylib] (posix,darwin): failed, try again with [libGLESv2.dylib]

SharedLibrary::open for [libGLESv2.dylib] failed (posix). dlerror: [dlopen(libGLESv2.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libGLESv2.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libGLESv2.dylib' (code signature in <B48F2D27-E9C4-30EF-A948-C]

SharedLibrary::open for [libEGL.dylib]: not found in map, open for the first time

SharedLibrary::open for [libEGL.dylib] (posix): begin

SharedLibrary::open for [libEGL.dylib] (posix,darwin): call dlopen

SharedLibrary::open for [libEGL.dylib] (posix,darwin): failed, try again with [libEGL.dylib]

SharedLibrary::open for [libEGL.dylib] failed (posix). dlerror: [dlopen(libEGL.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libEGL.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libEGL.dylib' (code signature in <5C3ABCC5-722A-3AEA-AF5B-6CEEFF8D10]
```

opengl_cxt_log.txt says nothing

2. Running emulator through terminal (`/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_4_API_32`) causes such output:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 30.9.4.0 (build_id 7759208) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
ERROR   | EglOsGlLibrary: Could not open GL library libGLESv2.dylib [dlopen(libGLESv2.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libGLESv2.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libGLESv2.dylib' (code signature in <B48F2D27-E9C4-30EF-A948-C]

ERROR   | EglOsEglDispatcher: Could not open EGL library libEGL.dylib [dlopen(libEGL.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libEGL.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libEGL.dylib' (code signature in <5C3ABCC5-722A-3AEA-AF5B-6CEEFF8D10]
```

1. Running the same command in terminal, but with SUDO works well `sudo /Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_4_API_32`. It runs emulator in "apple-native" mode and everything works fine. It also produces some INFO logs:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 30.9.4.0 (build_id 7759208) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed
INFO    | added library /Users/xset/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib
createOrGetGlobalVkEmulation: warning: instance doesn't support external memory capabilities, picking first physical device
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 root@unknown]
INFO    | Rootcanal has **NOT** been activated.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /Users/xset/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/avd/running/pid_12298.ini
```

So what should I do to made it run natively through Android Studio without sudo-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was successfully fixed in Android Emulator revision 31.2.7.
Just go to Android SDK Manager and update it!

According to [android emulator release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator):

```
31.2.7 (February 1, 2022)

[Bug fix] Emulator hanging error on M1 machines.
```

Comment: for what's worth, i'm getting the same issue on mac m1 + emu 31.2.10.0 + android studio chipmunk 2021.2.1 patch 1. works fine with `sudo`, idk why.